# correlation coefficient problem

Tags: statistics

The national farming association has data on the amount of pesticide used per acre and the percentage of fruit that has been contaminated by insects per acre, for $117$ farms. These two variables have a correlation coefficient $r=-0.8$. For a farm that uses an amount of pesticide that is $2$ standard deviation above the mean amount of pesticide used, we would predict the percentage of contaminated fruit will be $1.6$ SD below the mean.

Can anyone explain how $1.6$ below the mean is calcuated to me?
I can only think of sum of $\cfrac{z_x z_y}{n-1}= r.$

Comment: $-1.6=2 \times (-0.8)$.

Comment: what formula is that?

Comment: First, this is not an exact formula, this is a prediction. There is usually some error. You may find this helpful http://onlinestatbook.com/2/regression/intro.html